# Recover multiple input data

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, input

i have my jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap");
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button");

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a     href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
     });

     $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
         e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
     })
});
```

And my HTML :

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

From : https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery

I would like to know, i can i recover each data from for each input added and save in my databse (MySQL) ?
I would like to use php if possible or jQuery if i have no other possibility.
Thanks a lot,

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap your input fields with a `<form action="processing_page.php" method="POST">` and `</form>`

then when form is submitted you will be able to access the data within your processing_page.php in such way.

`$valuesArray = $_POST['mytext'];`

you can use it in foreach statement to do something with each one (like in this example print it out)

```
foreach($valuesArray as $value) {
    echo "<br>$value";
}
```

EDIT: if you get stuck with implementing a form, here is a basic  [overview/tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp). Make sure to check out the sections on form itself, action and method.

EDIT2: if you plan on storing the values to the database or showing it on another page, make sure to sanitize all user provided data. There are some good practices explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php).

Comment: Hoo i'll try this, thanks, i'll keep you informed :)